# Angular Material MatMomentDateModule imports all Moment locales

Tags: angular, angular-material, momentjs, angularfire

I'm using MatMomentDateModule for Angular Material's matDatePicker component.
But this imports all locales for Moment.js even though I need only one:

[main bundle module's sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpFYa.png)

Is there a way to tell it to only import the locales I need?

In my module I import it like:

```
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatMomentDateModule } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    ...
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatMomentDateModule,
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatMomentDateModule,
    ...
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try specify it in your Providers array of app.module.ts?

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB'},
  ],
})
export class MyApp {}
```

See link: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#setting-the-locale-code